# Using os.path.isfile() to Remove Directories

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that creates a list of all files and directories from a directory. The function will then remove any files that start with `~` and remove any directories. I believe I am somehow using the `os.path.isfile()` function incorrectly as when I set it to True I get a list with nothing in it, and when I set it to false, I get a list that removes the `~` files but keeps the directories.

```
def getfiles(directory):
    New_List = []
    List1 = os.listdir(directory)
    for i in List1:
        if str.startswith(i,"~") is False and os.path.isfile(i) is True:
            New_List.append(directory+"/"+i)  
    return New_List
```

Comment: It should be `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, i))`

Comment: If you want to populate `New_List` with files whose names starts with `~`, then your `if` must be `if i.startswith('~') and os.path.isfile(i):`.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Why are you using `is False` and `is True`?

Comment: I do not understand why people down vote answers without leaving at least a comment explaining why they did it. :-/ Maybe they don't know they lose reputation as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In summary, `os.path.isfile` returns `True` if a path is a file but `False` if it is a directory. `os.path.isdir` returns `True` only if a path is a directory. However, `os.path.exists` returns `True` if it is a file or a directory. In addition, you can also use `subprocess` to modify or delete files with shell commands.
For example:

```py
import subprocess
shell_command1 = 'ls ~*'
shell_command2 = 'rm -f ~*'
subprocess.call(shell_command1, shell=True)
subprocess.call(shell_command2, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative with standard library module [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (It requires Python 3.4+ though):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def getfiles(directory):
    return [o for o in Path(directory).rglob('~*') if o.isfile()]
```

And if you want to remove those files instead:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for o in Path(directory).rglob('~*'):
    if o.isfile():
        o.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

Or, using `getfiles()` we defined above:

```py
for o in getfiles(directory):
    o.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

All in pure Python and using standard libraries.

Both examples will scan `directory` **AND** its sub-directories for files whose names start with `~`. If you want to scan just `directory`, replace `rglob` with `glob`.